# Gremlin traverse a tree to find highest level of each branch that doesn't contain nodes with a specified property

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases

I have a tree that is like a country containing states containing cities. For example, the graph below has the United States containing California and Texas, which contains 2 cities in each state.

One or more cities is marked, meaning it has a property "marked" set to "true". In the graph below, "San Francisco" is marked.

```
g.addV().property('name','united states').as('united states').
addV().property('name', 'california').as('california').
addV().property('name', 'los angeles').as('los angeles').
addV().property('name', 'san francisco').property('marked', 'true').as('san francisco').
addE('contains').from('united states').to('california').
addE('contains').from('california').to('los angeles').
addE('contains').from('california').to('san francisco').

addV().property('name', 'texas').as('texas').
addV().property('name', 'dallas').as('dallas').
addV().property('name', 'houston').as('houston').
addE('contains').from('united states').to('texas').
addE('contains').from('texas').to('dallas').
addE('contains').from('texas').to('houston')
```

I would like to run a Gremlin query that returns all unmarked cities and states. If a state has no marked cities, it should return the state. If a state has marked cities, it should not return the state but should return the cities that have not been marked.

This code works correctly below. It outputs Texas because no cities in Texas are marked, and returns Los Angeles because Los Angeles is the only city not marked in California.

```
g.V().has('name', 'united states').repeat(out()).until(not(
  repeat(out()).until(has('marked','true'))
)).not(has('marked','true')).values('name')
==>texas
==>los angeles
```

However, is this the most efficient query? It seems inefficient to me because I'm traversing the tree, but then at each node of the tree I'm traversing the tree below that node again, which seems bad. Is there a more efficient query? Note: the use of 3 levels (country, state, and city) is just an example. My actual use case has more than 3 levels and each branch of the may have variable number of levels, so the repeat(out())'s are necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't happen all too often but it doesn't seem as though Gremlin wants to handle this one easily. Searching for a solution took me in circles for some time and so, reluctantly, I'm just going to paste some attempts by Daniel Kuppitz to try to solve this one (though the deeper things went the more questions that arose over the rules of the algorithm):

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('name','united states').as('united states').
......1> addV().property('name', 'california').as('california').
......2> addV().property('name', 'los angeles').as('los angeles').
......3> addV().property('name', 'san francisco').property('marked', 'true').as('san francisco').
......4> addE('contains').from('united states').to('california').
......5> addE('contains').from('california').to('los angeles').
......6> addE('contains').from('california').to('san francisco').
......7> 
......7> addV().property('name', 'texas').as('texas').
......8> addV().property('name', 'dallas').as('dallas').
......9> addV().property('name', 'houston').as('houston').
.....10> addE('contains').from('united states').to('texas').
.....11> addE('contains').from('texas').to('dallas').
.....12> addE('contains').from('texas').to('houston').
.....13> 
.....13> addV().property('name', 'arizona').as('arizona').
.....14> addV().property('name', 'pima').as('pima').
.....15> addV().property('name', 'maricopa').as('maricopa').
.....16> addV().property('name', 'tucson').property('marked', 'true').as('tucson').
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('name','united states').as('united states').
......1> addV().property('name', 'california').as('california').
......2> addV().property('name', 'los angeles').as('los angeles').
......3> addV().property('name', 'san francisco').property('marked', 'true').as('san francisco').
......4> addE('contains').from('united states').to('california').
......5> addE('contains').from('california').to('los angeles').
......6> addE('contains').from('california').to('san francisco').
......7> 
......7> addV().property('name', 'texas').as('texas').
......8> addV().property('name', 'dallas').as('dallas').
......9> addV().property('name', 'houston').as('houston').
.....10> addE('contains').from('united states').to('texas').
.....11> addE('contains').from('texas').to('dallas').
.....12> addE('contains').from('texas').to('houston').
.....13> 
.....13> addV().property('name', 'arizona').as('arizona').
.....14> addV().property('name', 'pima').as('pima').
.....15> addV().property('name', 'maricopa').as('maricopa').
.....16> addV().property('name', 'tucson').property('marked', 'true').as('tucson').
.....17> addV().property('name', 'phoenix').as('phoenix').
.....18> addE('contains').from('united states').to('arizona').
.....19> addE('contains').from('arizona').to('pima').
.....20> addE('contains').from('arizona').to('maricopa').
.....21> addE('contains').from('pima').to('tucson').
.....22> addE('contains').from('maricopa').to('phoenix')
==>e[36][25-contains->30]
gremlin> 
gremlin> solution1 = {
......1>   g.V().has('name', 'united states').
......2>     until(select('result').or().not(outE('contains'))).
......3>       repeat(sack(assign).
......4>              map(out('contains').
......5>                  group().
......6>                    by(coalesce(values('marked'), constant('false')))).
......7>              choose(select('true'),
......8>                       coalesce(select('false'), sack()).project('result'),
......9>                       select('false').unfold())).
.....10>     coalesce(select('result').unfold(),
.....11>              sack()).dedup().
.....12>     values('name')
.....13> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@3f63a513
gremlin> 
gremlin> solution2 = {
......1>   g.V().has('name', 'united states').
......2>     until(select('result').or().not(outE('contains'))).
......3>       repeat(sack(assign).
......4>              map(out('contains').
......5>                  group().
......6>                    by(coalesce(values('marked'), constant('false')))).
......7>              choose(select('true'),
......8>                       union(select('false').unfold(), sack().project('result')),
......9>                       select('false').unfold())).
.....10>     coalesce(select('result').unfold(),
.....11>              sack()).dedup().
.....12>     values('name')
.....13> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@53f0d09c
gremlin> 
gremlin> solution1()
==>texas
==>los angeles
==>pima
==>maricopa
gremlin> solution2()
==>texas
==>california
==>pima
==>maricopa
gremlin> 
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'tucson').properties('marked').drop()
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'pima').property('marked', 'true').iterate()
gremlin> 
gremlin> 
gremlin> solution1()
==>maricopa
==>texas
==>los angeles
gremlin> solution2()
==>arizona
==>texas
==>california
==>maricopa
```

Perhaps some of this can put you on the right track to solve your problem or perhaps the answer simply is that there is no better solution with Gremlin than what you currently have.

I'm not sure if is an option for you, but I suppose you could consider doing a `subgraph()`, then mutating it in such a way so as to give you hints as to what will be found further down the tree at which point you could then query the subgraph more efficiently. Whether the cost of doing that is worth the effort I suppose depends on the size and depth of these trees.